# Make svg logo have transparent background

Tags: html, css, svg

I added this svg logo to my website. I saved it in illustrator with not background and when it pops up in the web browser its has a white background. Not sure how to fix this or what the problem may be.

[heres what it looks like on my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNcql.jpg)

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/n3ov9czj/

```
<img src="images/logo.svg" />
```

Comment: can you link the logo please :), it doesnt show up in the fiddle

Comment: Looks like your SVG contains the white background

Comment: @Srax how could i link it so you guys can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?
[Jsfiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/8sL1jbsu/2)

Or was it more like this?
[Jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8sL1jbsu/3)

This obviously didnt work :(

```
svg { background: transparent; }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160453/discussion-on-answer-by-srax-make-svg-logo-have-transparent-background).

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your linked image (logo?) black areas are actually transparent, showing the background. White areas are actually the (logo) image. It's kind of a negative youre trying to accomplish in that case, I guess. I can see some text behind the letter **h**. It would be really more helpful with the actual svg logo image to figure out the problem.

Simply test colouring the image background.

```
<img src="images/logo.svg" style="background-color:grey"/>
```

If this is the case, then you probably want to apply the background image behind the logo or whatever was the idea you want to implement.

Comment: Image seems ok. But the background of the image is white, because it is blank. Nothing behind the logo. You can easily see if you test by styling the image background color to some actual color.